# problems storing hashmap in sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, sharedpreferences

I use the following 2 methods to store ArrayList of custom objects in my shared preferences.

```
 public ArrayList<BetDisplayer> getallopenbets() {
    allopenbets = new Gson().fromJson(pref.getString(ALL_OPEN_BETS, null), ALL_OPEN_BETS_TYPE);
    if (allopenbets == null) {
        allopenbets = new Gson().fromJson(pref.getString(ALL_OPEN_BETS, null), ALL_OPEN_BETS_TYPE);
        if(allopenbets == null){
            allopenbets = new ArrayList<BetDisplayer>();
        }
    }
    return allopenbets;
}
public void setallopenbets (ArrayList<BetDisplayer> listwriter) {
    this.allopenbets = listwriter;
    editor.putString(ALL_OPEN_BETS, new Gson().toJson(listwriter));
    editor.commit();
}
```

Where

```
    public static final String ALL_OPEN_BETS = "all_open_bets";

    private static final Type ALL_OPEN_BETS_TYPE = new  TypeToken<ArrayList<BetDisplayer>>() {}.getType();
```

This works perfectly fine. I tried applying the same logic to store a `HashMap<String,String>` using the following two methods however it doesn't seem to work as when I call getfinalteams I get an empty hashmap, even though i set it before properly.

```
 public HashMap<String,String> getFinalteams() {
    finalteams = new Gson().fromJson(pref.getString(FINALTEAMS, null), FINAL_TEAMS_TYPE);
    if (finalteams == null) {
        finalteams = new Gson().fromJson(pref.getString(FINALTEAMS, null), FINAL_TEAMS_TYPE);
        if(finalteams == null){
            finalteams = new HashMap<>();
        }
    }
    return finalteams;
}
public void setFinalteams (HashMap<String,String> listwriter) {
    this.finalteams = listwriter;
    editor.putString(FINALTEAMS, new Gson().toJson(listwriter));
    editor.commit();
}
```

Where

```
    public static final String FINALTEAMS = "finalteams";

    private static final Type FINAL_TEAMS_TYPE = new TypeToken<HashMap<String,String>>() {}.getType();
```

Comment: Can you add the result of `new Gson().toJson(listwriter)` just to be sure

Comment: {"3":"null","10":"null","6":"null","5":"null","4":"null","9":"null","11":"null","12":"null"}

Comment: That's what it's supposed to be, so that seems to work fine

Comment: Do you know from where? You try to assign `finalteams` 3 times (first 2 are the same), but do you get an empty HashMap because it loads an empty one, or because of the last `finalteams = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: I added a log call after the editor.putString line and made it log new Gson().toJson(listwriter) so I'm assuming it sets it properly

Comment: Annoying problem... What if, just to be sure the problem is in HashMap, you try saving and loading a normal (hardcoded) string... If it's null, something goes wrong saving, otherwise something else is overriding it

Comment: @Danielson I store a bunch of stuff in my shared preferences using the exact same structure and it all works fine

Comment: Nevermind, it's working suddenly, not sure how...can I close this question somehow?

Comment: I think if you write your answer, and then accept it... Too bad I couldn't help :(

Comment: I don't really have an answer tho, it just kinda worked :D no worries, thanks for the help :)